# Как поменять надпись, зашифрованную в PHP файле?

Tags: php, распознавание

Файл в такой кодировке. Как раскодировать и поменять текст внутри?

\40\x20\40\x20\40\x20\x20\40\x20\x20\40\40\40\40\x20\x20\40\40\x20\40\40\40\40\x20\x20\x20\x20\40\74\57\144\151\x76\76\15\12\x20\40\x20\40\40\40\x20\x20\x20\x20\40\x20\x20\x20\40\x20\x20\x20\x20\40\x20\x20\40\40\40\x20\40\40"; goto ttALt; eV6GO: qadl5: goto MkdSH; rTwXo: language_attributes();

Comment: Что в начале файла?

Comment: <?php
 goto sbBk0; P3sEb: echo "\40\x20\40\x20\40\x20

Comment: Это реально полезный код или вас взломали?

Comment: это шапка сайта, нужно поменять только одну надпись. А это может быть когда взломали? Или специально так кодируют?

Comment: Я обычно такое видел на взломанных сайтах. Может быть бывают неадекваты, которые "шифруют" код. Это какая-то CMS?

Comment: да сайт на  Wordpess

Comment: Если вы это видите в движке вордпресса - вас взломали точно. Сделайте резервную копию и принимайте меры к очистке кода и закрытию дыр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надпись не совсем зашифрована. Это экранирующие последовательности: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php

Гуглим и находим онлайн-декодер PHP. [Ответ следующий](https://www.unphp.net/decode/c4eb2e0a25008e1838586a5fdbd40a98/):

```
</div>
                            "; goto ttALt; eV6GO: qadl5: goto MkdSH; rTwXo: language_attributes();
```

Очевидно, всё, что до кавычки Вы можете поменять (почти) на любой текст, т.к вероятно до этого код с переменной, содержащей шаблон HTML. Любые символы могут быть приняты. Если необходимо, переводите строку обратно в экранирующие последовательности и вставляйте.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!